# Запуск файла .java

Tags: java, файлы

Как запустить файл .javа, учитывая то, что мне нужно запустить 2 файла одновременно? Нужно, чтобы код не отображался. 
P.S Я новичок, неумеха, вообщем банальные ошибки простительны. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Никак. Файлы с расширением .java - это файлы исходного кода. Чтобы получить то, что можно запустить, их надо сначала скомпилировать.

Comment: Мне кажется вам нужен `jar`, который эквивалентен `exe` на винде

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Расширение `.java`, это исходный код файлов, написанных на языке программирования *Java*, который был первоначально разработан компанией *Sun Microsystems*, но сейчас поддерживается компанией *Oracle*. Этот язык использует объектно-ориентированный подход, где используются структурированные типы данных, называемые классами. Классы, в свою очередь, используются для создания экземпляров объектов во время выполнения. Эти файлы хранятся в текстовом формате. Это означает, что *Java* файлы можно редактировать в приложениях *Java IDE*, таких-например как Intellij IDEA, NetBeans, Eclipse, а также в стандартных текстовых редакторах.

Файлы с кодом *JAVA* компилируются в файлы `.CLASS` с помощью *Java*-компилятора. *CLASS* файл содержит байт-код, который может быть выполнен *Java Virtual Machine* (JVM). Вот собственно файл с расширением `.class` вы можете запустить в командной строке.